# R: Write function that finds 0 and replaces it with certain value

Tags: r, function, replace

I am trying to write a function to find zeros in one variable and replace those zeros with the result of a division including the value of another variable.

My data:

```
id apr_days apr_hours    
A      1       7 
B      2       14 
C      0       8 
D      0       15
E      0        0
```

I am trying to capture the amount of time a person utilizes a certain policy. In all cases where apr_hours is >0, there needs to be an entry in apr_days to indicate the respective amount of days (value of apr_hours /7, rounded down in order to show only even counts).

Expected output:

```
id apr_days apr_hours    
A      1       7 
B      2       14 
C      1       8 
D      2       15
E      0       0
```

What I am trying to tell R is: For all observations that have `apr_hours  >0 & apr_days ==0`, take the respective value of `apr_hours`, divide it by 7; round down to even count value and replace the `0` in `apr_days` with this value.

What I think the function should be structured like:

```
if apr_hours == 0 {   
    if true: do nothing     
    } else {    
   check whether apr >0   
   if true: do nothing    
   } else {     
   calculate apr_hours/7,
   round down to even counts,
   and replace the 0 of apr_days with this result
   }
```

I am just completely lost and down know how to exactly write the code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 7, 2, 14, 0, 8, 0, 15, 0, 0), 5, 2, byrow = T)
a[, 1] <- replace(a[, 1], which(a[, 1] == 0), floor(a[a[, 1] == 0,  2]/7))
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
within(df1,apr_days[apr_days==0] <- apr_hours[apr_days==0] %/% 7)
#   id apr_days apr_hours
# 1  A        1         7
# 2  B        2        14
# 3  C        1         8
# 4  D        2        15
# 5  E        0         0
```

And here's a solution following (and correcting) your logic:

```
df1$apr_days <-
  ifelse(df1$apr_days == 0 & df1$apr_hours > 0,
         df1$apr_hours %/% 7,
         df1$apr_days)
```

Or jut recompute all :

```
df1$apr_days = df1$apr_hours %/% 7
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Both versions kind of worked out, although I like the second Version better because it directly overwrites the old values with the new ones. However, there is one issue: It seems to work out only for values greater than 7; for hours below (4; 6; etc.) it still gives me a 0; I would like to have a 1 in days here aswell. Do you know what to do?

Comment: you wanted it rounded down, so  `6/7 == 0.857...` will be rounded to 0. use `ceiling(x/7)` to round up, or `round(x/7)` for regular rounding

Answer (score 0):

```
if (apr_hours[i] == 0) apr_hours[i] = Math.Floor(apr_days[i]/2)
```

Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: I will try it in a second. The thing is that in the regular case, apr_days should be already filled. Thus, I am only trying to reach those mistakes where apr_days is not filled by default. And I am not sure whether your function does this; it appears to me that it simply overwrites all apr_days observations - am I right here?

Comment: On a side note: What does Math.Floor do?

Comment: it's javascript :). use `floor`

Comment: R does not recognize i - what am I suppossed to fill in there?

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` and using integer division `%/%` you can do:

```
setDT(df)
df[apr_days == 0, apr_days := apr_hours %/% 7]

print(df)

    id apr_days apr_hours
1:  A        1         7
2:  B        2        14
3:  C        1         8
4:  D        2        15
5:  E        0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be achieved by using `ifelse` as:

```
df$apr_days = ifelse(df$apr_days == 0 & df$apr_hours > 0 , 
                 floor(df$apr_hours/7), df$apr_days)
df
#    id apr_days apr_hours
# 1  A        1         7
# 2  B        2        14
# 3  C        1         8
# 4  D        2        15
# 5  E        0         0
```

Comment: Thanks, that works out! I am facing the same issue as in the answer above that hours >7 will not result in an entry of "1" in apr_days. I am trying to solve this with a new command: df$apr_days = ifelse(df1$apr_days == 0 & df$apr_hours <=7, 1). However, this did not work out. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @Hanna good that worked. I think you meant `hours < 7`. If so, you can try nested `ifelse`: as `df$apr_days = ifelse(df$apr_days == 0 & df$apr_hours < 7, 1, ifelse(df$apr_days == 0 & df$apr_hours > 0 ,            floor(df$apr_hours/7), df$apr_days))`

Comment: Thank you very much, you (and everyone else who helped here) are my personal hero! It worked out, wohoo!

Comment: @Hanna happy to help. You can accept an answer by clicking on `tick` in left of answer box.